# Fail to download a remote https svg file but embed inside <img> is good

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, httparty

I have a `https` link, embedded into `<img>`, everything is good. Such as https://jsfiddle.net/Lbhhtt6n/. However, if you try to download link directly such as directly open it with browser with link https://version.gitlab.com/check.svg?gitlab_info=eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiOC4xNi4wLXByZSJ9 , then `404` error returned.

Due to this issue, I cannot check head by `httparty`

```
response = HTTParty.head('https://version.gitlab.com/check.svg?gitlab_info=eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiOC4xNi4wLXByZSJ9')
puts response.success? # always return false
```

What's the magic behind it? Anyone could enlighten me? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of magic is this ?

Comment: Why the code above always return false? It is a valid link and it shall return true for `response.success?`? Why I cannot directly download link by browser but embed inside the <img> is ok?

Comment: Seriously ??  . . . . man this is befuddling !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gitlab only gives you the image if you inform [HTTP Refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) header. Otherwise it responds with 404. See details at https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/sales-process/version_check.

When you try to obtain resource by your browser address bar or by any other tool without explicitly setting that header, you will get 404.

It works when loading as page resource (img tag for example) because browse will send that header for you.

Give a try yourself to see it in action:

> $ curl -v https://version.gitlab.com/check.svg?gitlab_info=eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiOC4xNi4wLXByZSJ9
>
> $ curl -v https://version.gitlab.com/check.svg?gitlab_info=eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiOC4xNi4wLXByZSJ9 -e stackoverflow.com

---

See the difference shown by Chrome Developer Tool:

As page resource:

[image]

From address bar:
[image]

Comment: Awesome! I tried in https://www.hurl.it/ as long as you have a `Referer` header, it return 200 ok. Thanks so much!